# Why is this linear functional unbounded in $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $\Delta_\Gamma$ be the Laplace-Beltrami operator on a closed hypersurface $\Gamma$ embedded in $R^n$.
We define a linear functional
$$
f(v) = (\Delta_\Gamma x_\Gamma, \Delta_\Gamma v)_\Gamma
$$
where $x_\Gamma: \Gamma \ni x \mapsto x \in R^n$ is the coordinate map, $(a,b)_\Gamma$ is the inner product of $a$ and $b$ on $\Gamma$.

I was told that $f(v)$ is not unbounded if $v$ is in $L^2$. But I don't know why and how to show that claim.

Comment: I don't understand what is $v$ and how $f$ does not depend on $x$ (or $x_{\Gamma}$)